# Testing for void methods dependency using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, easymock

I have a Mainclass that I need to test which is dependent on other class.
Now I am creating a mock for that class
How to test void methods using easymock

```
MainClass{

  mainClassMethod(){
    dependencyClass.returnVoidMethod();
    //other code
  }
}

TestClass{

    @Before
    setUpMethod(){
        DependencyClass dependencyClassMock = EasyMock.createMock(DependencyClass.class);
    }

    @Test
    testMainClassMethod(){
        EasyMock.expect(dependencyClassMock.returnVoidMethod()).andRetur //this is not working
        dependencyClassMock.returnVoidMethod();
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes(); //If I use this, it is invoking the method.

    }
}
//My dependency class code
DependencyClass implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER = "authenticationManagers";

    returnVoidMethod(){
        ProviderManager pm = (ProviderManager) getApplicationContext().getBean(AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER); //this is returning null

    }
     //othercode
     //getters and setters of application context
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Do you mean `public void returnVoidMethod(){`

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Easymock Documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html) you don't put the method inside an `expect()` (since there is no return).  You can just call the mocked method by itself and if it is in "record" mode then it is implied an expect.

```
dependencyClassMock.returnVoidMethod();
```

If you need to throw an Exception or say the method can be called anyTimes() you can use `expectLastCall()`

```
@Test
public void testMainClassMethod(){

    dependencyClassMock.returnVoidMethod();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes();

    ...
     //later to replay the mock
    EasyMock.replay(dependencyClassMock);

    //now this method is actually called
    dependencyClassMock.returnVoidMethod();

}
```

EDIT : Just noticed that you don't have the dependencyClassMock as  field:

```
public class TestClass{
    DependencyClass dependencyClassMock

    @Before
    setUpMethod(){
        dependencyClassMock = EasyMock.createMock(DependencyClass.class);
    }

...//rest of class is as described above
```

Answer (score 0):

@dkatzel
the test is completely wrong..... you are calling manually a method and the you verify if it was called...of course it was! ...that's not the right way (my opinion)

A better way (my opinion) would be to extend the mehod class you would like to test, override that method and in the body just put a boolean variable as a flag to k now if the method was called or not....you don't even need to use EasyMock

Example

```
Class DependencyClass {
 public void returnVoidMethod() {
  [.... content ...]
 }
} 

Class A_test {

 @Test
 public void checkVoidMethodCalled() {
  A_mod obj = new A_mod();
  mainClassMethod();
  assertTrue(obj.called);
 }

Class A_mod extends DependencyClass {
 boolean called = false;

 @Override
 public void returnVoidMethod() {
  called = true;
 }
}


}
```

You are welcome.